# how to make query for fetching particular post id?

Tags: php, mysql

hai i'm trying to make a commenting system using php and mysql (no jquery or ajax)
the problem is how to find the id of the post that user comments i used a while loop for that it posts to all the posts so far i'm here.....

```
//user data is set
if (isset($_POST['comment'])) {
    //variables to post in database
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
    $com_from = $_SESSION['user'];
    $com_to = $_GET['u'];
    $com_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $u = $_GET['u'];

    //query to get the id of the post in the `post` table
    $que = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE `post_to` = '$u'");
    if ($que) {
        //loop through all the posts ad get all ID
        while ($ro = mysql_fetch_array($que)) {
            $pst_id = $ro['post_id'];
            //query inside the while loop for getting the post ID i think here is the problem
            if (!empty($_POST['comment'])) {
                $com_query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments SELECT '','$comment',`post_id`,'$com_from','$com_to','$com_time' FROM `posts` WHERE `posts`.`post_id` = $pst_id");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are `$u` and `$com_to` ?

Comment: Code & comments you have provided is not readable.

Comment: @HamedKamrava $u is the $_GET['u'], where the url is profile.php?u=username and $com_to is commented to the user (mean the user's profile where the post lives)

Comment: Your script is vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: @Gumbo how, can you explain plz??

Comment: None of the parameters for the two SQL statements is formatted properly. Have a look at [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/53114)

Comment: ya ya i know it bro but this is for education purpose only only i will use this app :D

Answer (score 1):

First of all you dont have to go through the loop for quering post table.
If you are commenting a specific post pass its ID in html form with hidden type.

```
// here 1 is id of post
<input type="hidden" name="postid" value="1">
```

Then you can write insert query like :

```
if (isset($_POST['comment'])) {
    //variables to post in database
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
    $com_from = $_SESSION['user'];
    // $com_to is post id and i believe comment table contain field to store post id
    $com_to = $_POST['postid'];
    $com_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$que = mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments VALUES('$comment','$com_to','$com_from','$com_time')");
}
```

Comment: how to use it dynamically for many posts??

Comment: you know like there are many posts how to insert the html for different values??

Comment: fetch post_id dynamically and echo in your value in hidden field.

Comment: while looping your post dynamically echo post id in hidden field
`<input type="hidden" name="postid" value="<?php echo "Your post id" ?>"/>`

Comment: yes it works :D but above comment echos itself but the following works "<input type="hidden" name="p_id" value="'.$pst_id.'">"

Answer (score 0):

I have provided the insert query with my limited understanding,

```
 $pst_id = $_POST['postid']; // from form 

 $com_query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments  values ('$comment','$pst_id','$com_from','$com_to','$com_time') ");
```

I can help you more, if you share your `comments` table structure.

**Note** Use mysqli_* functions instead of mysql_* functions `(deprecated)`

Comment: thank you :D and wait i will post my comments table structure and `post_id` is a foreign key

Comment: id | comment | post_id | comment_by | commented_to | comment_time |
`post_id` is foreign key

Comment: While submit the comments you need to pass or `$_POST` the posts table `primary` id. Then here you retrieve the post id and update the comments accordingly.